# Unable to fetch private key from .net x509certificate2 object to bouncycastle AsymmetricCipherKeyPair

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, pkcs#7

I was trying to get keypair for **pkcs-7 signature**  an **X509Certificate2** object from this code.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Cert.PrivateKey;
RSAParameters rsaparam = key.ExportParameters(true);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keypair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsaparam);
```

This works fine if **X509Certificate2 object is created using .pfx** file like this

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(".pfx file path", "password");
```

it works fine.
 but when the **certificate is listed from certificate store** like this

```
 X509Certificate2 cert;
 X509Store UserCertificateStore = new X509Store("My");
 UserCertificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 var certificates = UserCertificateStore.Certificates;
 foreach (var certificate in certificates)
 {
    if (certificate.Thumbprint==thumbprint)
    {
       cert=certificate;
       break;
    }
 }
```

it throws an exception with the message - **Key not valid for use in specified state.**

after @Crypt32 answer tried using RSA method sign hash

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

using (SHA256Managed sHA256 = new SHA256Managed())
{
    byte[] hash = sHA256.ComputeHash(data);
    return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
}
```

but the signature was **not in PKCS#7 format**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because BouncyCastle attempts to get raw key material (literally, export) from .NET object while actual key is not marked as exportable. In Windows systems, keys are stored in cryptographic service providers which control all key operations. When you need to perform a specific cryptographic operation, you are asking CSP to do a job and it does without having to expose key material to you. If the key was imported/generated in CSP as exportable, you can ask CSP to export key material. If this flag was not set, CSP won't give you the key.

I don't know how BouncyCastle works, but if it expects raw key material, then you need exportable private key in your certificate.

Comment: thanks, is there any workaround to achieve this, I have to sign a sha256 hash using the certificate present in windows key store and CSP Hardware

Comment: you have to call Windows code (methods in .NET objects) to sign the data. Say, any suitable overload in `RSA.SignData` method. `RSA` is a base class the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` derives from). For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt132675.aspx

Comment: will RSA create detached pkcs7 signature

Comment: `RSACryptoServiceProvider csp =
 (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

using (SHA256Managed sHA256 = new SHA256Managed())
{
    byte[] hash = sHA256.ComputeHash(data);
    return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
}` 

I tried this but the signature I got was **not in PKCS#7 format**

Comment: To create PKCS#7 message, you have to use `SignedCms` class which constructs a PKCS#7 message from your data and computes signature by using a signer certificate.

Comment: but `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner` do not support sha256 hash to sign

Answer (score 0):

To answer the underlying question, "How do I make a PKCS#7 SignedData message signed with RSA+SHA-2-256?"

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md#bcl says that SHA-2-256 not only works in 4.7.1, but it's the default now:

> Updated SignedXML and SignedCMS to use SHA256 as a default over SHA1. SHA1 may still be used by selected as a default by enabling a context switch. [397307, System.Security.dll, Bug]

On older frameworks it's possible via:

```
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(content);
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
return cms.Encode();
```

Where "[2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1](http://oid-info.com/get/2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)" is OID-ese for SHA-2-256.